# How can I find a MongoDB document, querying by a mongoose virtual field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, virtual

How, by using the 'findOne'/'find' functions of mongoose, can I find a specific document, where the results are filtered by a virtual field which does not appear physically in the db?

**I'll try to further explain:**

In my 'User' model, I have a field called 'email'. I want to create an alias for 'email' as 'userkey' for other functions in my nodejs app (mostly login validations and stuff).

*To create the alias, I did this:*

```
userSchema.virtual('userkey').get(function()
{
    return this.email;
});
```

Now, after I created the alias, I want to filter my search result the following way:

```
restApi.post('/login', function (req, res)  // (using expressjs)
{
    User.findOne({'userkey': req.body.userkey}).exec(..);
}
```

How can I do this efficiently and without creating any more methods\field etc to save up time and memory?

The alias is very important, because in the future of the app I'll add more ways to login, and I want to be able to quickly switch between fields to be associated with 'userkey'. This alias saves the trouble of changing the entire app (which is a huge programming principle), and can help me to add more logic which is going to be necessary in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Virtuals do not exist on the document stored in mongodb, so there's nothing to query on.

Comment: oh, is there a known work-around that I can implement maybe? or at least an other way to create an alias for a field?

Comment: okay thanks. i'll tag this answered since i can only assume that there is no way other than that.